# Map keys array to values array

Tags: php, arrays

I have keys array and values array.

```
$keys = [
   0 => 'Test'
   1 => 'John'
   ...
   22 => 'Kate'
   23 => 'Bob'
]
```

I run an `array_filter($values)` to clear out unwanted empty values, then I end up with something like this

```
$values = [
   1  => '$3'
   22 => '$10'
   23 => '$50'
]
```

My goal is achieving

```
[
  'John' => '$3',
  'Kate' => '$10',
  'Bob'  => '$50'
]
```

Is there a way to map it this way without creating a for loop and a new array to assign each index individually?

I tried using `array_intersect_key` but couldn't get close at all.

**Edit:** My version looks like below but I'm sure there are better ways:

```
$selectedCols = array_intersect_key($keys, array_flip(array_keys($values)));
array_combine($selectedCols, $values);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first combine the two arrays using `array_combine` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php), then apply `array_filter` on the result. That should do it.

```php
array_filter(array_combine($keys, $filters));
```